# Invalid parameter 1 specified for datediff

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm getting error when i run this TSQL Statement

I USED THE CASE funcation as well but still getting error
the error is

> "Msg 1023, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid parameter 1 specified for datediff."

```
select(( (100/(DATEDIFF(MIN(initiative_start_plan),
MAX(initiative_end_plan),DAY)))*DATEDIFF(GETDATE(),
MIN(initiative_start_plan),DAY)/100*-1)>1,1,
(100/(DATEDIFF(MIN(initiative_start_plan),
MAX(initiative_end_plan),DAY))) *DATEDIFF(GETDATE(),MIN(initiative_start_plan),DAY)/100*-1)

  FROM [TansiqDashBoard].[dbo].[IntativeProject]



    select CASE WHEN (((100/(DATEDIFF(MIN(initiative_start_plan),
       MAX(initiative_end_plan),DAY)*DATEDIFF(GETDATE(),
       MIN(initiative_start_plan),DAY)/100*-1)>1 THEN 1 ELSE 
       (100/(DATEDIFF(MIN(initiative_start_plan), MAX(initiative_end_plan),DAY)))*DATEDIFF(GETDATE(),MIN(initiative_start_plan),DA 
       Y)/100*-1) END 

  FROM [TansiqDashBoard].[dbo].[IntativeProject]
```

---

**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.**

```
select CASE WHEN (((100/(DATEDIFF(day,MIN(initiative_start_plan),
  MAX(initiative_end_plan))*DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),MIN(initiative_start_plan))/100*-1) > 1 

  THEN

  1 
  else
  (100/(DATEDIFF(day,MIN(initiative_start_plan),MAX(initiative_end_plan))*
  DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),MIN(initiative_start_plan))/100*-1))END 

  FROM [TansiqDashBoard].[dbo].[IntativeProject]
```

Comment: According to the documentation for `DATEDIFF`, the first argument should be the datepart (e.g. `DAY`), second argument is start date and third argument is end date. Seems you might have your arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: im new in this can you help me out please

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DATEDIFF function in SQL takes the datepart as the first parameter.  In your case it would be DAY:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**In reference to your comment:**
 It appears you do not have enough parenthesis in your statement.
Try this:

```
select CASE WHEN (((100/(DATEDIFF(day,MIN(initiative_start_plan),
  MAX(initiative_end_plan))*DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),MIN(initiative_start_plan))/100*-1)))) > 1
```

Comment: I changed but now getting   tjis error "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'."

Comment: Check my answer above

Comment: Watch out  for integer division as well. It might be rounding to whole number. to avoid this either cast or use 100.00